# How to make the title look like this using maketitle

Tags: latex

[image: Output Expected]

I tried something like this. But it is not working. I want to put the author object on the left side, the date object on the right side and below them, the title should come and a line should come below the title

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={180mm,266mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=14mm,
 }

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.4em}       
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    \newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

    \makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
    \renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
      %\parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
      {\@author \hfill \@date}
      \par
      \centering
      {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
      \HRule\par%
    }
    \makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

    \title{
    Motivation Letter
    }

    \author{
    Application for Master of Science\\
    Computer Science\\
    The University of X\\
    }

    \date{
    Sourav Chakraborty\\
    x@gmail.com\\
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you bother to use `\maketitle`? Make title is to enforce a similar look in standardized documents like journal articles, thesis front pages, etc. Not a for a motivation letter. `\author` is supposed to look like a person name, `\date` to a date, etc.  You can find packages that provide formats for letters on ctan.org. Or you can just use your own formatting which the `article` format without using `maketitle`.

Comment: I want to create that format. But I don't know in which way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Creating this kind of format is just standard latex.

As a starting point that can be largely improved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={180mm,266mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=14mm,
 }

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.4em}     
\begin{document}
~\\[-1cm] % to control vertical position
Application for anything\hfill Paul random\\ 
School of information\hfill paul.random@gmail.com\\
The university of Nowhere\hfill Appt A...\\
{\centering\textbf{\large Statement of purpose}\\[-0.2cm]} % to have the rule closer
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} % to control rule width

To Whom It May Concern


Blah blah and so on...
\end{document}
```

[image]